# Changing font size for a Text View in nib (xib)

Tags: cocoa-touch

I'm using Text View in my App, but I cannot change the font, size or colour of the text box. It's not listed in atrributed. I can change UILabels. But I cannot seem to find where it is for the Text View. Im using xcode 3 (yes I know its old)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should open the font dialog (Font / Show fonts), then click on the uitextview and change the font in the font dialog.